# Как реализовать непрерывную интерграцию в Android?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день окутываюсь миром ci нашел много тутториалов но вот для Android все тихо.Как работать с Cİ в андроиде ?какие технологии есть для этого ?где можно посмотреть ?прошу любую информацию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я делал так:

1. Берём VPS любого хостера. Нужен довольно мощный комп. У меня - `4Гб` операты, `6ГГц` проц и `SSD`.
2. Ставим туда `Java`, `Git`, `Gradle`, `Tomcat`.
3. Выбираем систему для CI. Я выбрал `Jenkinks`, но есть другие, например, `TeamCity`.
4. Прописываем CI из какого репозитория `checkout` делать.
5. Прописываем ему собрать проект `gradlew assembleRelease`
6. Заливаем в маркет плагином к `Jenkins`

Comment: Больше всего мне понравилось мощность 6мгц))))

Comment: в принципе я тоде смотрел на jenkins

Comment: @elik, исправил) `Jenkins` хорош, да. Главное - не пытаться для него писать скрипты на `shell`/`bash` - будет адЪ и мучения. Советую писать на `groovy` в `pipeline`

Comment: Tomcat-то зачем? )

Comment: @Nofate, ну... `Jenkins` у меня в виде `*.war` файла, засим и запускаю его `Tomcat`-ом)

Comment: Jenkins прекрасно живет в докере

Comment: @YuraIvanov, мне хотелось на уже существующее окружение всё это натянуть)

Answer (score 3):

Можно заюзать [Bitbucket pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines), [Circle Ci](https://circleci.com/), [GitLab Ci](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/)
Настраиваются с помощью одного скрипта

У меня собирает circle ci, умеет работать с bitbucket и github
Пробовал Bitbucket pipelines, но там лимит на время, наверно около часа в месяц

Comment: спасибо большое